# transform object to derived type in c++

Tags: c++

I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass : public BaseClass {
public:
  double get_e() { return m_e };
  double set_e(double) { m_e = e};
  double get_f1() { return f_1 };
  // ... things can be a bit more complicated,
  // e.g. non 1-1 mapping between get/set-ers and private fields
private:
  double m_e;
  double m_f1; // many other fields
};
```

and an external function

```
void very_slow(MyClass& c) {
 // slow computation based on get_f1(), ...
 // call c.set_e
}
```

I want to put them together, but in a lazy way:

```
class MyLazyClass : public MyClass {
public:
   double get_e() {
     if (m_calibrated) return m_e;
     else {
        set_e(very_slow(*this));
        m_calibrated = true;
        return get_e();
     }
   }
private:
     m_calibrated = false;
};
```

My main code looks like:

```
ObjectContainer* objects = nullptr;
retrieve_objects(&objects); // a container of pointers to MyClass
for (MyClass* obj_ptr : objects) {
    // ... maybe decide to skip this object (continue)
    very_slow(*obj_ptr);
    // ... use obj_ptr->get_e()
}
```

`ObjectContainer` type and `retrive_objects` are provided by my framework and I can't change them. If I want to use `MyLazyClass` instead the naive way would be to create a copy

```
ObjectContainer* objects = nullptr;
retrieve_objects(&objects);
for (MyClass* obj_ptr : objects) {
    MyLazyClass obj_lazy(*obj_ptr);
    // ... use obj_lazy->get_e()
}
```

as you can imagine this copy is very inefficient and I would like to avoid that. What could be a solution? One solution is maybe move-constructor, can you give an example? Other ways? I would like to define a `retrive_objects_lazy`

Comment: sorry for the title, change if you have a better one. I know I can't convert a base class to a derived type in c++.

Comment: "I know I can't convert a base class to a derived type in c++" why not?

Comment: Why do you need a `MyLazyClass`? Either make that behavior built in the main class or just write a lambda that does this lazy computation if you only use it in one place.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov: I can't change `MyClass`. Many users will use `MyClass` or `MyLazyClass` in ways I cannot predict. I want to simplify their work, hiding the detail of `very_slow` inside the class they use, but at the same time in a lazy way if they decide to skip one particular objec in the loop, before looking at `get_e`

Answer (score 0):

> as you can imagine this copy is very inefficient

You've only shown two double sub-objects of `MyClass` (and one base, which may or might not be empty). Judging by what we've seen, I would imagine the copying to be very efficient.

> One solution is maybe move-constructor

As far as the members that you've shown, copying is same as moving, so this would not make any difference. Unless there are sub-objects that are slow to copy that you haven't shown.

---

What you could do is define a

```
class MyLazyClassContainer {
    ObjectContainer* objects;
    std::vector<bool> calibrated;
    // ...
};
```

This way you can retrieve the objects directly into your custom class without copying.

Comment: `MyClass` is very complicated (the two `double`s is just an example), with tons of subobjects, referenced by it (`MyClass` has pointers to other objects as members)